# Compare two JSONs and put equal objects to a new array in VUEJS

Tags: json, vuejs3

I am new to VUEJS3 and I have two JSON files. One is a header JSON and the another is a details JSON. I want to compare **details JSON's id** with **header JSON's id** and put **details JSON** object to an array if id matched. I tired using nested foreach, I wanna know weather there is another correct way to do it.

Header JSON

```
[
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00001",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "course"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00002",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "course"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00003",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 0,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "course"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00004",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "course"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00005",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "course"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00006",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "pack"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00007",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 0,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "pack"
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00008",
        "IS_ACTIVE": 1,
        "COURSE_TYPE": "pack"
    }
]
```

Details JSON

```
[
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00001",
        "CULTURE_ID": "en",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "Test description",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00001",
        "CULTURE_ID": "sl",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "පරීක්ෂණ විස්තර අංක එක",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00002",
        "CULTURE_ID": "en",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "Test description",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00003",
        "CULTURE_ID": "en",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "Test description",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00003",
        "CULTURE_ID": "sl",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "පරීක්ෂණ විස්තර අංක දෙක",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00003",
        "CULTURE_ID": "ta",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "சோதனை விளக்கம்",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00004",
        "CULTURE_ID": "en",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "Test description",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    },
    {
        "CARD_ID": "00005",
        "CULTURE_ID": "en",
        "IMAGE_PATH": "",
        "CARD_DESCRIPTION": "Test description",
        "CARD_DATE": "2023-06-10",
        "CARD_LINK": ""
    }
]
```

The way I did,

```
    import AcademyHeaderData from '../data/academy.json';
    import AcademyDetailsData from '../data/academy_details.json';
    
          data() {
                return {
                      AcademyHeader: AcademyHeaderData,
                      AcademyDetails: AcademyDetailsData,
                      filteredAcademyData: []
                }
          },

          mounted(){

                this.AcademyHeader.forEach(pal => {
                      this.AcademyDetails.forEach(p2 => {
                            if (pal.CARD_ID.includes(p2.CARD_ID)) {
                                  this.filteredAcademyData.push(p2);
                            }
                      })
                })
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ES6 syntax `filter` and `some` to get the same result

```
const temp = detailsJSON.filter((detail) => {
  return headersJSON.some((header) => header.CARD_ID === detail.CARD_ID);
});
```

The `some` checks if the CARD_ID of the current object in headersJSON is equal to the CARD_ID of the current object in detailsJSON. If a match is found, the `some` method returns true.

The `filter` method is called on the detailsJSON array. It iterates over each object in detailsJSON and applies a filtering condition (`some` method). It will return a detail object if the `some` condition inside is true.